# Autollenado de inputs en tabla html

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una tabla normal en HTML, a la que en la primera columna, he agregado un checkbox, y cada fila la creo mediante php, de unos datos que vienen de la bd.

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="regTable">
                <thead>
                <th>columna1</th>
                <th>colum...</th>
                <th>colum...</th>
           </thead>
                <tbody>
       @foreach ($servicios as $key => $servicio)
                    <tr>
                      <td> <input type="checkbox" id="cbox1" value="first_checkbox"> </td>
                      <td> </td>
                      <td>
                          <input type="text"  name="name" required>
                      </td>

                   </tr>
      @endforeach
                </tbody>
   </table>
```

Me pidieron que se pudiera organizar cada columna, dependiendo uno le diera click.
esto lo solucioné con. tablesorter() de js.

y ahora me piden que los checkbox, los pueda seleccionar de manera masiva, es decir

Si tengo 100 filas, yo pueda darle click al primer check, y luego por decir click al check # 30, y de manera automatica todos los checks intermedios se selecionen.
no tengo idea de como podria hacer esto. si alguien me puede ayudar? con algun metodo que exista o algo donde pueda guiarme? se lo agradezco mucho.

este seria el primer paso, ya que el segundo paso seria, que una vez se seleccionen los checks, a estos seleccionados, se les asigna un mismo INPUT que esta en otra columna.

es decir, la tabla tiene filas y columnas, cada fila tiene un check, unos datos y un campo input.
y a las filas que tengan marcadas los check, se les debe asignar un mismo input, ejemplo.. "1" o "2", etc, en los inputs que tengan los checks seleccionados.

cualquier ayuda, por minima que sea, será de gran ayuda. gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres puedes tener un check al principio de la tabla o que tenga un position sticky para que si la tabla es muy grande tengan siempre acceso a este. Cuando le den click (le agregas un eventListener) a este con javascript tendrías un array de todos los checkbox y luego con un:

```
CheckBoxes.forEach(checkBox=> checkBox.checked = true)
```

Así tendrías la función para poder recorrer todos los checkbox y activarlos y lo último que tendrías que hacer es: tener un input (supongo que de tipo text) y luego
sería vincular la fila de cada checkbox selecionado: se me ocurre que los checkbox tengan un name el cual sea el mismo que el id de la tr o table-row.

Espero haberte ayudado. Bye